# How is it possible to be infected by a Trojan without downloading anything suspicious?

Tags: windows-10, security, malware, trojan

After conducting a full scan on my Fujitsu Windows 10 laptop yesterday (Nov. 01, 2022), I got informed of this threat: Trojan:HTML/CryptoExtortBTC.A, with the detail "This program is dangerous and executes commands from an attacker."

I do not do anything about cryptocurrency. Nor have I downloaded anything suspicious to this computer. This seems to be a new malware with the only search result containing its name being [this link](https://malwarefixes.com/threats/trojanhtml-cryptoextortbtc-a/). However, its name sounds similar to "Trojan:HTML/CryptoStealBTC", which seems to be [discussed in Dell forum as a false positive](https://www.dell.com/community/Virus-Spyware/Dell-Update-triggers-CryptoStealBTC-warning-with-Microsoft/td-p/8158570). However, as described above, my computer is not from Dell.

With affected items:
file: C:$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-2502570151-1049385929-2667336535-500$R9PV95S.csv
file: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\records_30d.csv

I looked up briefly about such phenomena (i.e. getting infected by Trojan without downloading anything suspicious) and found [another user reporting on the similar experience](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/windows-defender-offline-not-finishing-is-the/8d0bfc32-1c67-4d4e-a3a2-20675cb67d2f) (albeit a different Trojan).

What is the reason behind such phenomena? How can we ensure that something similar would not happen again?

Comment: I'd be inclined to think of a csv as likely being a false positive. There should be no executable, it's a flat text file. Send it to https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your hint. Unfortunately, I can no longer find the two files. I think they have already been removed after I asked the defender to remove the threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not have specifically intended to download any files or executables, but by browsing *any* website you are downloading hundreds of files of various different types.

If you were browsing a website showing tables of data then csv would not be an uncommon format for downloaded data to be in and you could easily have clicked a download button without realising it. Then your browser would simply drop the file in your downloads directory as csv is not a common file format your browser would understand.

If you browse dubious sites then the site might exploit this behaviour to drop files on your computer in the hope that you might run them.

The way to protect yourself is to visit trustworthy sites and to have a good antivirus and anti-malware solution that is kept up to date.

A file having been downloaded does not mean you are infected. A download is just a download. If you ran whatever payload was in the file then you might be infected.

Comment: Thank you. Two clarification questions:  "csv is not a common file format your browser would understand." So what kind of file format browsers would understand? HTML?
"by browsing any website you are downloading hundreds of files of various different types." Where can I check them?

Comment: Your browser knows html, it knows jpg, it knows css. All of the things that describe how to display a Web page are what your browser lives for. A csv is simply a data format, most commonly used for spreadsheets which isn't what your browser is trying to do. You can check everything your browser has downloaded by looking in the browser cache, Google "[my browser name] cache location" to find it but be aware it is unlikely to be in a friendly layout for humans to easily view.